# Find the reduction formula for the expression given below.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate  $\displaystyle \int \frac{\cos(2nx)}{\sin(x)}dx$

I tried to apply by parts directly but it didn't work so I applied some trig identities like half angle formulae for $\cos(2x)$ and therefore separated terms but I always find my self stuck at some steps in the process. Hints will he good.

Comment: Have you tried just working out the $n=1,2,3$ cases to see if there is a pattern?  Maybe you can put together an induction?

Comment: I could not find anything outta that mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(n) = \int \frac{\cos 2 n x}{\sin x} \, \mathrm{d}x  \text{.}  $$

Then \begin{align*}
    f(0) &= \ln \tan(x/2) +C  \\
    f(1) &= 2 \cos(x) + \ln \tan(x/2) +C  \\
    f(2) &= 2 \cos(x) + \frac{2}{3} \cos(3x) + \ln \tan(x/2) +C  \\
    f(3) &= 2 \cos(x) + \frac{2}{3} \cos(3x) + \frac{2}{5} \cos(5x) + \ln \tan(x/2) +C  \\
\end{align*}

Looks like an induction could show $f(n) = f(n-1) + \frac{2}{2n-1} \cos((2n-1)x)$.

Note that \begin{align*}
\cos(2nx) &= \cos((2n-1)x + x) \\ 
&= \cos((2n-1)x)\cos(x) - \sin((2n-1)x)\sin(x)  \text{,}
\end{align*}
which could be handy.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
\begin{align}
\frac{\cos(2nx)-1}{\sin(x)}&=\text{Re}\left(2i\frac{e^{i2nx}-1}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}\right)
=\text{Re}\left(2ie^{ix}\frac{e^{i2nx}-1}{e^{i2x}-1}\right)\\
&=\text{Re}\left(2ie^{ix}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{i2kx}\right)
=\text{Re}\left(2i\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{i(2k+1)x}\right)
\end{align}
where we used the fact that $z^n-1=(z-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^k$ with $z=e^{2ix}$.
Therefore
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\cos(2nx)-1}{\sin(x)}dx&=\text{Re}\left(2i\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int e^{i(2k+1)x}dx\right)=\text{Re}\left(2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{e^{i(2k+1)x}}{2k+1}\right)+C\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\cos((2k+1)x)}{2k+1}+C.
\end{align}
Finally
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\cos(2nx)-1}{\sin(x)}dx&=\int\frac{1}{\sin(x)}dx+\int\frac{\cos(2nx)-1}{\sin(x)}dx\\&=
\ln\left(\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\right)+2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\cos((2k+1)x)}{2k+1}+C.\end{align}

Comment: We havent delt with complex integrals yet.

Comment: Now you have a formula $\int\frac{\cos(2nx)-1}{\sin(x)}dx=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\cos((2k+1)x)}{2k+1}+C$. Prove it by induction.

Comment: O thanks. Gotcha.